# (undefined method `to_datetime' for 0:Fixnum) for edit f.datetime_select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails and I have a problem to get parameters of type datetime and pass them to edit page. The idea is that there is a table called week which contains information about courses and the starting week(date) of each course, user could create and edit these weeks. I have a form page for edit and create the courses' name and their start date. I use f.datetime_select for getting start date of each course from user. here is the form and index page:

index(first) page:

```
 %tbody
    - @weeks.each do |week|
      %tr
        %td= week.course ? week.course.name : "unassigned"
        %td= week.start.strftime("%a, %d.%m.%Y").to_s
        %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_week_path(week)
        %td= link_to 'Destroy', week, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

form page:

```
= form_for @week do |f|
  - if @week.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@week.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this week from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @week.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .form-group
    = f.label :course
    = @course.name
  .form-group.form-inline
    = f.label :start
    = f.datetime_select :start, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }}, {required: true}
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save', :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

There is no problem by creating a new date but I have problem in editting the dates which user save in the above form. actually when the user click on edit page, datetime error is shown as follows:

```
F, [2018-01-25T21:16:43.454087 #819] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_datetime' for 0:Fixnum):
    11:     = @course.name
    12:   .form-group.form-inline
    13:     = f.label :start
    14:     = f.datetime_select :start, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }}, {required: true}
    15:     //= f.date_select :start, {}, { :class => "form-control" }
    16:   .actions
    17:     = f.submit 'Save', :class => "btn btn-primary"
  app/views/weeks/_form.html.haml:14:in `block in _app_views_weeks__form_html_haml___241486880657666967_43852860'
  app/views/weeks/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_weeks__form_html_haml___241486880657666967_43852860'
  app/views/weeks/edit.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_weeks_edit_html_haml___597540861062441854_41928920'
```

and here is the controller file:

```
class WeeksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :admincheck
  before_action :set_week, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /weeks
  # GET /weeks.json
  def index
    @weeks = @course.weeks
  end

  # GET /weeks/new
  def new
    @week = Week.new
  end

  # GET /weeks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  # POST /weeks
  # POST /weeks.json
 def create
    @week = Week.new(week_params.merge(course_id: @course.id))
    if @week.save
      redirect_to '/weeks'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /weeks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /weeks/1.json
  def update
    if @week.update(week_params)
      redirect_to '/weeks'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /weeks/1
  # DELETE /weeks/1.json
  def destroy
    @week.destroy
    redirect_to '/weeks'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_week
      @week = Week.find(params[:id])
    end

    list through.
    def week_params
      params.require(:week).permit(:start,:course_id)
    end
end
```

this is the definition of table in schema.rb:

```
 create_table "weeks", force: true do |t|
        t.datetime "start"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.integer  "course_id"
    end
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason `start` is an Integer? that's the reason why you're having this problem.

Comment: start is defined as datetime type in db. and it is not defined as int!!

Comment: in your Rails console, what does  `Week.columns_hash['start'].type` return?

Comment: this just return error: Gem Load Error is: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer    and shows some backtrace  for bundler and gem

Comment: Can you put the contents of your schema.rb into your post, and/or provide a public repo where this error is occurring so someone can take a look?

Comment: I updatet my post and add the schema.rb for week table.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is (or was) a rails between `4.0.0` and `4.0.3`: [this is a known bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25571) that [was fixed in 4.0.4](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25571#issuecomment-230347673).

So the best solution in that case is simply to upgrade rails.